# 階層構造の文字列を抽出する方法について

Tags: linux, shellscript, sh, awk

以下のようなテキストファイルを、シェルスクリプトにてCSVファイル形式に加工したいと考えています。
Linux上で加工出来れば、手法については拘りはありません。
実現方法が思いつかない為、アドバイス等を頂けると助かります。

・テキストファイル

```
ltm virtual /Common/vip-A {
    destination /Common/192.168.1.1:80
    ip-protocol tcp
    mask 255.255.255.255
    pool /Common/pool-A
    profiles {
        /Common/fastl4_default { }
    }
    source 0.0.0.0/0
    translate-address enabled
    translate-port enabled
}
ltm virtual /Common/vip-B {
    destination /Common/192.168.1.2:80
    ip-protocol tcp
    mask 255.255.255.255
    pool /Common/pool-B
    profiles {
        /Common/clientssl-www.hoge.jp {
            context clientside
        }
        /Common/tcp { }
    }
    source 0.0.0.0/0
    translate-address enabled
    translate-port enabled
}
ltm pool /Common/pool-A {
    members {
        /Common/192.168.2.1:80 {
            address 192.168.2.1
        }
    }
    monitor /Common/tcp 
}
ltm pool /Common/pool-B {
    members {
        /Common/192.168.2.2:80 {
            address 192.168.2.2
        }
    }
    monitor /Common/tcp 
}
```

・CSV出力例

```
vip-A,192.168.1.1:80,tcp,255.255.255.255,pool-A,fastl4_default,0.0.0.0/0,enabled,enabled
vip-B,192.168.1.2:80,tcp,255.255.255.255,pool-B,www.hoge.jp,0.0.0.0/0,enabled,enabled
pool-A,192.168.1.1:80,192.168.2.1,tcp
pool-B,192.168.1.2:80,192.168.2.2,tcp
```

補足になります。
・実機の設定ファイルを、一覧表で管理するのが目的で進めています。
・階層構造の形式で、括弧でくくられた1つの塊を1行にしたいのですが、
　awkコマンドで抽出することを思いついたのですが、改行の条件をどうしたら良いのかで悩んでいます。

Comment: 確認ですが、`ltm virtual /Common/vip-B { ... }` の部分は、`vip-B,192.168.1.2:80,tcp,255.255.255.255,pool-B,clientssl-www.hoge.jp,clientside,tcp,0.0.0.0/0,enabled,enabled` となるのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`}`だけの行を終端とし、終端の行以外の改行コードを`,`に置換すればよいと思います。

```
sed 's/^}$/}^D/' | tr '\n' '^E' | tr '^D' '\n' | tr '^E' ',' | sed 's/^,//'
```

^Dや^Eは制御文字です。入力に出現しない文字ならなんでもいいです。
以下実行結果です。不要な情報の削除はしてません。
「階層構造の形式で、括弧でくくられた1つの塊を1行にした」だけです。

```
ltm virtual /Common/vip-A {,    destination /Common/192.168.1.1:80,    ip-protocol tcp,    mask 255.255.255.255,    pool /Common/pool-A,    profiles {,        /Common/fastl4_default { },    },    source 0.0.0.0/0,    translate-address enabled,    translate-port enabled,}
ltm virtual /Common/vip-B {,    destination /Common/192.168.1.2:80,    ip-protocol tcp,    mask 255.255.255.255,    pool /Common/pool-B,    profiles {,        /Common/clientssl-www.hoge.jp {,            context clientside,        },        /Common/tcp { },    },    source 0.0.0.0/0,    translate-address enabled,    translate-port enabled,}
ltm pool /Common/pool-A {,    members {,        /Common/192.168.2.1:80 {,            address 192.168.2.1,        },    },    monitor /Common/tcp ,}
ltm pool /Common/pool-B {,    members {,        /Common/192.168.2.2:80 {,            address 192.168.2.2,        },    },    monitor /Common/tcp ,}
```

Answer (score 1):

*本当に* *本当に* *本当に* 汚いワンライナーでよければこんな感じになるけど・・・

```
$ cat /tmp/bigip.conf | perl -nE '($w) = $_ =~ m!^.*\s(?:/.*/)?([^{}\s]+)!; if (/^}\s*$/) { say join ",", grep { length } @buf; @buf = () } elsif (/^\s*[a-z]+\s*\{\s*$/) { next } else { push @buf, $w }'
vip-A,192.168.1.1:80,tcp,255.255.255.255,pool-A,fastl4_default,0.0.0.0/0,enabled,enabled
vip-B,192.168.1.2:80,tcp,255.255.255.255,pool-B,clientssl-www.hoge.jp,clientside,tcp,0.0.0.0/0,enabled,enabled
pool-A,192.168.2.1:80,192.168.2.1,tcp
pool-B,192.168.2.2:80,192.168.2.2,tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

方針だけ。。

多分、今回のケースに一番適しているのは perl6 の grammer を用いることではないかなと思っています。

ただ、自分は perl を記述したことがないので、フルの回答は作成できなさそうだ、と思っています。